# Isolated AC to DC converters in series with unequal output voltages and output current ratings

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I am trying to connect two isolated switching AC to DC converters in series to make a split supply of -48Vdc (using +48Vdc converter), ground reference, and +60Vdc.

R1 is a minimum load, R2-C1 and R4-C2 are low pass filters, R3 and R5 are bleeder resistors.

Before sparks start to fly, I have a couple of questions regarding the circuit below.

1. Is it ok to have the protection diodes at the end of the RC filters rather than immediately across outputs?
2. Besides Schottkys, is it ok to use fast rectifiers?

and finally,

3. Anything else that could cause problems with this circuit?

[image]

Comment: My opinion is that this is insane. Why do you need so many "bleeding" resistors? You have a 48V/60V PSU and 470 ohm resistor for warming the air - 10% of SMPS power is wasted for what purpose? Lastly, I would flip the lower circuit, so that both SPMS output are connected.

Comment: I guess i could leave out all the 100k resistors, and caps would discharge through 0.1 and 470 ohm resistors. If i dont have 470 ohm "heaters" there, the supplies might become unstable with output loads disconnected, no ?

Comment: If i flip the bottom circuit, then poorly filtered smps output will feed the upper ground of 60V converter.

Comment: I hope you are not suggesting that i flip the 48V converter outputs. The point is to get either -48v,0v,60v or 0v,48v,108v, depending on reference point.